# How to make mod_remoteip and mod_evasive work together

Tags: apache-2.4, haproxy, httpd, mod-security

I have several Cento7 machines running Apache 2.4. They are behind a load balancer. The load balancer pass X-Forwarded-For header with client IP. In order to have mod_evasive to use the real client IP, I enabled mod_remoteip.

Here is my config for mod_remoteip

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
```

I can confirm it is working since I see apache logs the real client IP using this format

```
LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
```

However the mod_evasive seems to still use the load balancer IP. Here is the config for mod_evasive

```
 DOSHashTableSize 3097
 DOSPageCount 2
 DOSSiteCount 50
 DOSPageInterval 1
 DOSSiteInterval 1
 DOSBlockingPeriod 10
 DOSLogDir "/opt/logs/mod_evasive"
```

It generates log files in `/opt/logs/mod_evasive`, the files are still named with `dos-<load balancer IP>`.

How can make mod_evasive to use the real client IP?

Comment: Hi ! Any update or answer to this topic ?... :/ Have the same problem with apache + mod_remoteip behind nginx loadbalancer.